# Regular expression to hunt references to jquery version files in a large body of code

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a large number of files to sift looking for references to jQuery. The project has been badly controlled and there are multiple versions and some other libs prefixed jQuery.

I shall use AgentRansack, employing its regex search capability.

Example of required hits

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/utility/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
```

Example of false positives

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"src="/utility/jquery/jsTree.v.1.0rc2/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/utility/jquery/contextmenu/jquery.contextmenu.r2.js"></script>
```

I think the rule needs to be something like:

- any text characters
- literal 'jquery-'
- any number of any characters excluding space
- literal '.js'
- any text characters

This may pick up mention of jQuery file versions in comments but I am happy with that.

What should the regex be?

With an online tool I built this, which seems to work against the test cases above.

```js
jquery-[0-9][.][0-9].[0-9].*.js
```

Anyone got anything better?

Comment: 1) Why can't you just look for `jquery-`? 2) Skipping jQuery dependencies is likely a bad idea.

Comment: AgentRansack looks like a run-of-the-mill text editor which lets you mass search in folders, right? The search for literally `jquery-` without regex...

Comment: Just to note.... I'm not asking for 'the best way to' because that would get voted to close.  In fact the plan is to expand the search string to include other dependencies later, which I hope & assume will be possible using the answer.  AgentRansack has a capable regex search capability, and its an available tool in the environment this stuff lives in. I didn't write out all the constraints as it would have made the question TLDR.

Comment: If it works why do you care? What requirements are you not explaining? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `jquery-[0-9.]+(\.min)?\.js` should suffice. The `(\.min)?` indicates an optional minified file.

If you want to be more specific, search for `jquery-\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\.min)?\.js`. Notice the `+` in `\d+`, added because the version number could have more than one digit.

Comment: Selected this as the answer because of the focus on the version numbers and the optional 'min' suffix. It was a close run thing with @Ryszard Czech's answer which also works well.

Answer (score 1):

Look:

- any text characters   - `.*`
- literal 'jquery-'     - `jquery-`
- any number of any characters excluding space - `\S*`
- literal '.js'                                - `\.js`

But why not simply

```js
/\bjquery-[^"\s]+\.js\b/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/YQBMom/2)

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  jquery-                  'jquery-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"\s]+                  any character except: '"', whitespace (\n,
                           \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  js                       'js'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Comment: Thank you this works and was very well explained. I prefer @Peter Theony's answer because it is more specific on the version number pattern.  I voted you up because I can't pick 2 answers.